# .htaccess modify rewrite rule, but keep all other rules intact

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My `.htaccess` is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule page/sitemap /sitemap.php
RewriteRule music/(.*) /music.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule results/(.*) /results.php?q=$1
RewriteRule list/(.*)/(.*) /list.php?letter=$1&page=$2
```

which works as expected.

When I call `<a href="/page/sitemap">Sitemap</a>` it calls `sitemap.php` and I have a pretty URL.

Same way to `<a href="/music/pop">Pop</a>` it calls `music.php?slug=pop` and also is a pretty URL.

The question is concerning the `music/(.*) /music.php?slug=$1` rule; I want to remove the **music** so I can have **mysite.com/pop** as the final URL instead of **mysite.com/music/pop** but keep all other rules as they are.

If I try:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /music.php?slug=$1
```

This will not work, as I am affecting all calls but do not know how, or if it is possible to have the way I wanted.

Hope I could explain well my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/sitemap$ /sitemap.php [END]
RewriteRule ^results/(.+)$ /results.php?q=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^list/(.+)/(.+)$ /list.php?letter=$1&page=$2 [END]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /music.php?slug=$1 [END]
```

Using the `[L]` flag on my side seems to cause an Internal Server Error - not sure why that is. Using the `END` flag fixes it.

Have also changed `(.*)` to `(.+)` (excluding the music rule) to make it match 1 or more characters - if you do not want that behaviour, you can change it back so it matches 0 or more.

Essentially, what's happening here: We're first checking for specific rewrites. If those are not matched, then send everything to `music.php`. Any other specific rules you have should be added above the music rule, in the same format.

**Update:** Per your comment, the above conflicts with `index.php` rewrites and existing files. As an alternative, you should pass `(.*)` to `index.php` and have that file perform the purpose of `music.php`. Unfortunately, you cannot have two rules with the same rewrite pattern. See below (including the change to allow CSS/JS file etc.):

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/sitemap$ /sitemap.php [END]
RewriteRule ^results/(.+)$ /results.php?q=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^list/(.+)/(.+)$ /list.php?letter=$1&page=$2 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. Got the idea but because everything will be sent to music.php if I dont declare before I have problems with:

index.php
and all .css files, .js files and images that I call.
and calling other php files from other directories where I have other routines.

Think they are all falling in the last rule (music.php) so maybe things can be a little more complicated.

Thanks for any advice you could give.

Comment: I see - you didn't mention anything about an `index.php` file. Unfortunately, you can't have both. You'll have to send everything else to `index.php` and have that fetch *music* if it needs to. I will update my answer to reflect that.